# mousemove handler?

Tags: gwt

Can we add a listener for mouse move events on the main document in GWT? I'm not sure how to do this and if whatever I do add will interfere with other parts of GWT (like drag and drop?). In javascript I do this:

```
window.onload = function() { 
  document.onmousemove = function(e) { 
      alert("the mouse was moved!"); 
  }; 
}
```

I'm just not sure where to start, GWT got a bit confusing for me since the new stuff was introduce in 2.0 (I used to use 1.4),

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to monitor the movement of the mouse in the whole window, but a quick and dirty solution would be to wrap everything in a [`FocusPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusPanel.html) and add a handler via `addMouseMoveHandler(MouseMoveHandler handler)` (check the other interfaces that `FocusPanel` implements - there's quite a lot of them :)). AFAICT, this shouldn't conflict with anything else (drag&drop is not part of GWT, BTW ;)) - unless you start to mess around with the event itself (like stop propagating it) or something.